# How to activate keydown event by clicking specific button?

Tags: c#, 2d

I am developing 2D game(pacman)to improve myself in VB 2013 via c#,
and I want my key-down events activated by clicking specific button.(That is restart button shown when the game is over).Thanks for your help.

```
  //these are my keydown codes
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        int r = pictureBox5.Location.X;
        int t = pictureBox5.Location.Y;





        if (pictureBox5.Top >= 33)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                t = t - 15;


            }
        }


        if (pictureBox5.Bottom <= 490)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                t = t + 15;
            }
        }


        if (pictureBox5.Right <= 520)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                r = r + 15;
            }
        }

        if (pictureBox5.Left >= 30)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                r = r - 15;
            }

        }


        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up && e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            t = t - 15;
            r = r + 15;
        }





        pictureBox5.Location = new Point(r, t);
    }

//and that's the button I wanted to interlace with keydown event
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: And what key you are supposed to press when you hit the button? The code in the Form_Keydown depends totally on the value of the e.KeyCode so without a key you can't use that code neither with a refactoring

Comment: ı want all 4 main direction ways are activated (up right down left)

Comment: How this is even possible? The code cannot be all values together. In your form_keydown code there is an impossible if statement. The KeyCode cannot be both equal to Keys.Right and Keys.Up.

Comment: Actualy,at first I thought ı woudnt work but it realy works by the way:) pacman goes all 4 main direcion and 4 all secondary direction

Comment: however , just skip my example and can you give me a proper example if you understood my real question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of refactoring could help here. Suppose that if you hit the button the keycode to use is Keys.Down. In this scenario you can move all the code inside the Form_KeyDown to a different method called HandleKey

```
private void HandleKey(Keys code)    
{
    int r = pictureBox5.Location.X;
    int t = pictureBox5.Location.Y;
    if (pictureBox5.Top >= 33)
    {
        if (code == Keys.Up)
            t = t - 15;
    }
    if (pictureBox5.Bottom <= 490)
    {
        if (code == Keys.Down)
            t = t + 15;
    }
    if (pictureBox5.Right <= 520)
    {
        if (code == Keys.Right)
            r = r + 15;
    }

    if (pictureBox5.Left >= 30)
    {
        if (code == Keys.Left)
            r = r - 15;
    }

    // This is simply impossible
    if (code == Keys.Up && code == Keys.Right)
    {
        t = t - 15;
        r = r + 15;
    }
    pictureBox5.Location = new Point(r, t);
}
```

Now you can call this method from the Form_KeyDown event

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Pass whatever the user presses...
    HandleKey(e.KeyCode);
}
```

and from the button click

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pass your defined key for the button click
    HandleKey(Keys.Down);
}
```

Comment: Totally gratefull friend. Thank you